# Why can't I break out of this for loop?

Tags: javascript

This is a test for a site where I check if photo sources exist or not, if they don't I want to hide the extra panel that would show these photos if they exist. The problem is I can't get the `breakVar = true;` state to come out and the loop won't stop either, I've tried different ways to get it to stop with breaks/returns.

I test for the output of `testPhotos(currentProduct,display,breakVar);` and I want to get a "test-fail" return so I can hide the extra panel.

yeah the code kind of became ugly as I desperately tried to check states in progress of code execution.

I've tried putting the `break;` statement in different places but get "Illegal break statement" error

I get test failed in loop 8 times in my console.

```
var breakVar = false;

function triggerPhotoFail(breakVar) {
  breakVar = true;
  consol.log('triggerPhotoFail ran');
  return "test-fail";
}
function testPhotos(currentProduct,display,breakVar) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    // test if photos exists
    if (breakVar === true) {
      break; // get out of loop
    }
    var src = productArray[currentProduct]['subphoto-' + i];
    $.get(src)
    .done(function() {
      // photo exists
    })
    .fail(function(breakVar) {
      // photo does not exist
      console.log('test failed in loop');
      breakVar = true;
      triggerPhotoFail();
      console.log('breakVar change!: ' + breakVar);
    })
  }
  if (breakVar === true) {
    console.log('breaker var tested true');
    return "test-fail";
  }
  else {
    return "not acknowledged";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.get` is asynchronous. The loop has finished *before* the `done` or `fail` function has been called.

You need to replace the `for` loop with an iterator that gets advanced when the `done` function fires.

```
function testPhotos(currentProduct, display) {
  // This starts the loop
  var i = 0; next();

  function next() {
    // This replaces the regular "end of for loop" check
    if (i == 5) {
      return;
    }

    $.get(src)
      .done(function() {
        // photo exists
        i++; next(); // This does the "End of for loop increment" test and starts the next loop
      })
      .fail(function(breakVar) {
        // photo does not exist
        console.log('test failed in loop');
        triggerPhotoFail();
        // We don't call `next()` here, which breaks the loop
      });

  }
}
```

Comment: hey that's cool how you nested the function inside the function it calls, any reason for that? cleaner?

Comment: It stops `i` being a global.

Comment: Well you can as well use `let i` to limit `i`'s scope right?

Comment: @RaxWeber — No, there is no block to limit it to.

Comment: @Quentin What I mean is using the `for` loop, which itself is a block.

Comment: @RaxWeber — There isn't a `for` loop in my code, and the use of a `for` loop in the original code is the problem.

Comment: A random question, do you know if it's possible to hide the errors in console?

Answer (score 0):

You are **not** passing any argument to your `triggerPhotoFail()` function, which in its definition requires 1 parameter namely `breakVar`. Just **remove** all `breakVar` parameters from your function definitions and calls (`.fail(function()...`) because `breakVar` itself is already **global**.

Comment: yeah I noticed that, I didn't have the parameters before but I figured I'd add it to see if that was part of the problem. closure right? anyway thanks

Comment: Yes because if you put the `breakVar` as parameter of a function then its scope would be local only to the function.

Comment: Is that true? Even if breakVar is declared outside of say two different functions, if you passed breakVar into each function, wouldn't each function still be able to access it? Or if one function changed breakVar, the other function would not see that change?

Comment: If you use the same name of a global variable as parameter to a function, then you can only access the global variable using (browser-based client) `window['var']`.

Comment: I thought the point of passing the global variable as the parameter is to access the global variable... although you can set the function definition parameter as whatever, and what's actually passed is different. I think I understand.